# Suspend on exception in pdb

Tags: python, pdb

Is there a way to set a dynamic breakpoint***, suspend on exception, in pdb?

***dynamic in the sense of not tied to any line number

In pycharm (pydev), this is possible and is a nice feature, but often times, I have to use pdb due to limitations of the pycharm debugger (no jump functionality and/or the machine doesn't have pycharm).

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break)?

Comment: Er, yes, but they don't include this feature.

Comment: "If a second argument is present, it is an expression which must evaluate to true before the breakpoint is honored."

Comment: Yes i have read the docs thoroughly. I'm not asking how to set a breakpoint or breakpoint expression. I'm asking how to, regardless of the line number, break if the line will throw an exception.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `postmortem` mode:

```
try:
    code_that_may_raise_exception()
except Exception:
    import pdb; pdb.post_mortem()
```

This will break on exception and drop you into a debugger right where it is being raised from

Comment: Yeah but sadly the exception has already occurred and the code exits. What I'm looking for is to jump over the exception once it happens. REPL in the python shell can handle exceptions just fine without tossing the memory. This is the behavior I'm seeking.

Comment: Have you tried this?  It drops me into a debugger right at the `raise` statement